# How do I use value in Cleave JS react

Tags: reactjs, cleave

I want to use Cleave js for currency format.
My Cleave tag looks like this:

```
<Cleave className="input-numeral" 
        name="loanAmount"
        options={{  numeral:            true,
                    numeralDecimalMark: ',',
                    delimiter:          '.' 
                }}
        value={this.props.loanAmount} 
        onChange={this.props.handleChange}
 />
```

Suppose if the input is 82456.56

I want output something like this: 82.456,56.
The code is working fine if I do not use 'value' prop in this.
But I need to use value as I need the initial value from the props in formatted way.

What shall I do in this case to read the value from props initially and then to change it according to the user input?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        value : props.loanAmount
    };
}

onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        value: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.handleChange();
}

render() {
    return <Cleave className="input-numeral" 
            name="loanAmount"
            options={{  numeral:            true,
                        numeralDecimalMark: ',',
                        delimiter:          '.' 
                    }}
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={this.onChange}
    />
}
```

}

Comment: This is working fine for this option:  options={{numeral: true, numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'}}, but not for the above mentioned options.  For the above mentioned option it works if I input new value to it, but not working for the initial value from the props. If the value from props is 42342.43, output is 4.234.243 rather than 42.342,43

Comment: have you done the steps, I have done in `constructor` ?

Comment: Yes, I followed exactly the same and now it is working for options={{numeral: true, numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'}}, but not for options={{  numeral: true,             numeralDecimalMark: ',', delimiter: '.' }}